# Jenkins build has been failing due to classloader not found for Grab

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am really new to Jenkins, Groovy and Java. I try to create a test shared library for Jenkins that imports Java library. But build is failing due classLoader not found. I don't understand what is happening here. Could any one please point me in a right direction to find a solution for this.

```
package au.com.test.test

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group = 'com.amazonaws', module = 'aws-java-sdk', version =     '1.11.22'),
    @Grab(group = 'com.offbytwo.jenkins', module = 'jenkins-client', version = '0.3.7'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
])
import com.offbytwo.jenkins.client.JenkinsHttpClient
import com.amazonaws.* 
def prepTaskDefinition(File envStage) {
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(envStage)
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(input))
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder()
String line
List<String> secrets = new ArrayList<>()
while ((line=reader.readLine() != null)) {
    if ( ! line.contains("#")) {
        if ( ! line.contains("\$")) {
            //secrets.add(line.subString(line.indexOf("{") + 1, line.indexOf("}")))
            secrets.add(line.substring(line.indexOf("{") + 1, line.indexOf("}")))
        }
        JenkinsHttpClient jenkinsHttpClient = new JenkinsHttpClient(new URI("https://test.company.com.au"))

        for (String secret : secrets) {
            String path = String.format("https://test.company.com.au/job/Domain/credentials/store/folder/test/_/credentials/%s", secret);
            jenkinsHttpClient.get(path)
        }
    }
}
reader.close()
return out 





    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onNewInstance(GroovyInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:191)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedConstructor(Checker.java:188)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.constructorCall(SandboxInvoker.java:20)
    at taskDefinition.call(/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Domain/jobs/fe-server-search-results/branches/feature-nr.21obta/builds/55/libs/devops-jenkins-libraries/vars/taskDefinition.groovy:9)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:8)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:96)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor604.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.chooseClassLoader(GrapeIvy.groovy:184)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$chooseClassLoader.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:251)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:182)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onStaticCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:140)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:180)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:177)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedStaticCall.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:222)
    at au.com.domain.ecs.EcsTaskDefinition.<clinit>(EcsTaskDefinition.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onNewInstance(GroovyInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:191)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedConstructor(Checker.java:188)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.constructorCall(SandboxInvoker.java:20)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not using

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
```

from the [groovydoc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/api/groovy/lang/GrabConfig.html#systemClassLoader())

> public abstract boolean systemClassLoader
>
> Set to true if you want to use the system classloader when loading the grape. This is normally only required when a core Java class needs to reference the grabbed classes, e.g. for a database driver accessed using DriverManager.

It doesn't look like the script requires a Java class to reference these classes.

Comment: thanks John.. According to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41122, I had to move jenkins shared library to root level and removed  @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true) from my code to get it working

Comment: can you give post  your example in github. i have tried but still having 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab`